# Visit France without a hotel booking

Tags: france, mauritius, mauritian-citizens

I am from Mauritius. A friend of mine is coming to visit me in France for 2 months. He is from Mauritius. I have some questions regarding this.

1. For people from Mauritius, France allows them to come in the country provided they have a viaticum (reserve or allowance) of 120 € per day. How can he prove this? Is a bank statement enough?
2. Since he has a viaticum (reserve or allowance) of 120 € per day for his stay, is it sure that he will not have any problem on the border?
3. How much money does he need in cash with him, is a credit card enough?

Comment: Last time a friend hosted me in France they had to get that information from the préfecture, French bureaucracy is extra, but they should know what you need

Comment: @blackbird57, i do not understand what you mean ?

Comment: Where did you get this from (especially the €120 figure)?

Answer (score 1):

People who require a visa have a harder time as they need to submit a lot of information about their financial situation together with the visa application but for people able to travel visa-free (which is the case for citizens of Mauritius), credit card(s) are enough, you're not expected to have cash.

In theory, if you need to prove you have money at your disposal, a bank statement might be enough but I would not expect border guards to check that at all. You (or your friend in this case) might take one with you for peace of mind but do not volunteer this kind of things without being asked.

Having a proper [invitation/attestation that you intend to host him](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F2191) or at the very least your contact details would also be useful. That's actually more likely to be checked (because it goes to the purpose of the visit) than the exact amount of money your friend has.

Beyond that dress smartly, be confident, genuine and forthcoming about what you intend to do and everything should be fine.

Comment: Yeah, the attestion I asked from the Mairie, but the issue is that they are giving me only for one month due to my income, and he needs to be here for at least 2 months

Comment: @user1774937 I've stayed many times with friends in France, while the attestation is required, in practice few people get one before hosting, it's unlikely from my experience to cause a problem

Comment: but then, on the airport, they don't ask anything ?

Comment: @user1774937 They *can* ask just about anything but usually they don't take too much time. That's why being truthful and confident helps. If there is something unusual about you or you are trying to hide something, then it can indeed make you look suspicious and prompt additional investigation.